# Understanding proof of the characterization of local fields ( Neukirch, Algebraic Number Theory )

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm reading the Neukirch's Algebraic number theory, p.135 and stuck at understanding some points. I think that I am begginer of algebraic number theory, please understanding that it seems a little bit basic question.

In his book, he define the **local fields** as all fields which are complete with respect to a discrete valuation and have a finite residue class field. Then he proves next characterization of the local fields :

[image]

I'm trying to understand the above underlined statements

**Q.1)** First underlined statement : Assume that $K$ is a finite extension of $k=\mathbb{F}_p((t))$. To apply his theorem (4.8), it seems that $k=\mathbb{F}_p((t))$ should be complete with respect to some (what?) valuation. Is it true? I can't find an associated reference until now.

**EDIT for Q.1)** : It seems to be true, by construction of the field of formal power series $k((x))$ ( Neukirch's book, p.127 ).

**Q.2)** For the second underlined statement, why can we consider the residue class field extension? $\mathbb{F}_p$ is the prime field of the $K$? And $\mathbb{F}_p$ is the residue class field of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $\mathbb{F}_p((t))$? If so, why?

**EDIT for Q.2)** : It also seems to be true ; c.f. again refer to the p.127. (And until now I can't prove the statement rigorously for the case $\mathbb{F}_p((t))$ . )

**Q.3)** Third underlined statement : Why the closure $\mathbb{Q}$ in $K$ is the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to $v_p$? The closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $K$ is the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to $v|_\mathbb{Q}$? Then, since $v|_{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $v_p$ are equivalent, ..

**EDIT for Q.3)** : I think that I also can prove that "the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $K$ is the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to $v|_\mathbb{Q}$." Because, it seems true by the next proposition ( Note that $K$ is complete with respect to $v$ ) :

> Proposition : If $Y$ is the completion of $X$ and $X' \subseteq X$ (metric space), then the completion of $X'$ is its closure in $Y$.

Proof : Let $Y' := \bar{X'}^{Y}$. Since $Y'$ is a closed subset of complete metric space $Y$, it is complete too. Also, $X'$ is dense in $Y'$ by definition, so we’re done.  True ?

**Q.4)** Fourth underlined statement : Why $\operatorname{Char}(K) = p:= \operatorname{Char}(\kappa)$ ( $\kappa$ is the residue class field of the $(K,v)$ ) if $\operatorname{Char}(K) \neq 0$ ? A priori it seems easy and I can't prove it until now.

**EDIT for Q.4)** : This is true, using that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a local integral domain with field of fractions $K$ ! : c.f. [The nonzero characteristic of local integral domain is equal to the characteristic of its residue field?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4642613/the-nonzero-characteristic-of-local-integral-domain-is-equal-to-the-characterist)

**Q.5)** Finally, why can we view $\kappa = \mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)$ as a subfield of $K$ from the fact that $p(X)$ spits over $K$?

**EDIT for Q.5)**  : I think also we can prove this statement since : 1) first, consider the algebraic closure $\bar{\mathbb{F}_p}$ of the $\mathbb{F}_p$. 2) Second, write $p(X) = (x-k_1) \cdots (x-k_n) \in K[x]$ and $p(X)= (x-l_1)\cdots (x-\alpha) \cdots (x-l_n) \in \bar{\mathbb{F}_p}[x]$. 3) Thrid, $\bar{\mathbb{F}_p}[x]$ is UFD. 4) So, there exists $i$ such that $(x-\alpha)=(x-k_i) \in K[x]$. 5) So, we can view $\alpha \in K$. 6) So, we can view $\kappa=\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha) \subseteq K$.

Do these arguments seem to be working?

Can anyone helps?

Answer (score 2):

The valuation on $\Bbb{F}_p((t))$ is just $v(\sum_{n\ge N} a_n t^n) = N$ if $a_N\ne 0$ (which gives the non-archimedian absolute value $|r|=p^{-v(r)}$). Up to scaling there is only one discrete valuation on a local field (essentially because $(1+t)^{1/n} \in \Bbb{F}_p((t)), (1+p)^{1/n}\in \Bbb{Q}_p$ whenever $p\nmid n$). This plus the fact that $v$ extends to $K$ (a finite extension) implies that $\kappa_K/\Bbb{F}_p$ is a finite extension. The residue field is $\kappa_K = O_K/\mathfrak{m}_K$ where $O_K=\{ a\in K, v(a)\ge 0\},\mathfrak{m}_K=\{ a\in K, v(a)\ge 0\}$.

Next, before looking at general statements, you should really look at examples of finite extensions of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ (and $\Bbb{F}_p((t))$), their residue field, uniformizer (a $\pi_K$ such that $\mathfrak{m}_K=(\pi_K)$), Galois group, how Hensel lemma helps, and so on.

Comment: Thanks. It is somewhat helpful hint. I upload an edited question. Perhaps, can you see and explain for the question Q.3) more rigorously?