# The nonzero characteristic of local integral domain is equal to the characteristic of its residue field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $(A, \mathfrak{m})$ be a local integral domain with maximal ideal. If $\operatorname{Char}(\operatorname{Frac}(A)) \neq 0$ and $\operatorname{Char}(A/\mathfrak{m}) \neq 0$  , then $\operatorname{Char}(\operatorname{Frac}(A)) = \operatorname{Char}(A/\mathfrak{m})$ ?

This question originates from following linked question that I posed : [Understanding proof of the characterization of local fields ( Neukirch, Algebraic Number Theory )](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4642215/understanding-proof-of-the-characterization-of-local-fields-neukirch-algebrai). In the question, in particular for **Q.4)**, I asked why $\operatorname{Char}(K) = p:= \operatorname{Char}(\kappa)$ under the assumption $\operatorname{Char}(K) \neq 0$, where $K$ is a local field with (discrete) valuation $v$, and $\kappa := \mathcal{O}_K/ \mathfrak{m}_K$ is the residue field ( $\mathcal{O}_K$ is the valuation ring of $(K,v)$ and $\mathfrak{m}_K$ is its unique maximal ideal ( c.f. Neukirch's Algebraic number theory book p.121 ) ). Then note that since $\mathcal{O}_K$ is an local integral domain with field of fractions $K$, if our question is true, then we can show that $\operatorname{Char}(K) = p:= \operatorname{Char}(\kappa)$. Can anyone helps?

Comment: Show that for any rings $R$ and $S$, if there is a ring homomorphism $R\rightarrow S$, then the characteristic of $S$ divides the characteristic of $R$. Apply this to the canonical morphisms $A\rightarrow\mathrm{Frac}(A)$ and $A\rightarrow A/\mathfrak{m}$. Note that integral domains have prime characteristic.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out asociated theorem !~